# Counterexample for first order logic argument

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Find a counterexample to show that the following argument is not
>   valid:
>
> ∃xP(x), ∃x(P(x) → Q(x)) |= ∃xQ(x)

To my understanding, I have to a select a single element $x$ such that the premises are true but conclusion is false.

I can't find a counterexample: if I go with the domain: D={a}, $Q(a)=0$ (to make the conclusion false), then $P(a)$ must be $0$ to make the implication true. In doing so $∃xP(x)$ becomes false, so this isn't a countermodel to show that the argument is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT 1: There's two ways an element $a$ could witness "$\exists x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$": either by having $P(a)\wedge Q(a)$ hold, or by having $\neg P(a)$ hold (so that $P(a)\implies Q(a)$ becomes vacuously true).

HINT 2: The witnesses for "$\exists x (P(x))$" and "$\exists x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$" don't need to be the same element. That is, your sentence

> To my understanding, I have to a select a single element $x$ such that the premises are true but conclusion is false.

is incorrect.

---

Does this help?

Comment: Right, so I can have a domain D={a,b} and then make P(a)=1, P(b)=Q(a)=Q(b)=0 ?

Comment: @ak1652 Yup! Do you see why that's a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! ∃xP(x) would be true [x=a] , ∃x(P(x) → Q(x)) would still be true [x=b], and whatever I choose for ∃xQ(x) it will always be false

Comment: That's it exactly.

Comment: I thought x has to be the same throughout. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Indeed, that's a common tripping point. In symbols, "$\exists x(A(x)) \& \exists x(B(x))$" does **not** imply "$\exists x(A(x) \& B(x))$" (although the converse does hold). This can be made clearer by changing the names of the bound variables so that none are re-used: e.g. "$\exists y(A(y)) \& \exists z(B(z))$".